# Flutter only IOS crash issue

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crashlytics

I have a flutter app that uses multiple firebase calls. When the live version of the mobile application on a real device opens from standby mode it says it has crashed and asks to report the crash. I have crashlytics and have read xcode crash logs. Here they are I am stuck on this issue and it is heavily effecting users. I have **** out the actual uuid and other info.

From Crashlytics

> ````
> INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Failed to commit transaction:
> <LevelDbTransaction Backfill Indexes: 0 changes (0 bytes):> Failed: IO
> error:
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/775AB93F-A27D-4400-87C0-5316FCCA089F/Library/Application
> Support/firestore/__FIRAPP_DEFAULT/********************/main/000038.log:
> Operation not permitted (expected status.ok()) ```
>
> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
> 0  CoreFoundation                 0xa248 __exceptionPreprocess
> 1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x17a68 objc_exception_throw
> 2  Foundation                     0x546958 -[NSMutableDictionary(NSMutableDictionary) initWithContentsOfFile:]
> 3  FirebaseFirestore              0x45b74 (Missing UUID ********************************)
> 4  FirebaseFirestore              0x45644 (Missing UUID ********************************)
> 5  FirebaseFirestore              0x9926c (Missing UUID ********************************)
> 6  FirebaseFirestore              0x992fc (Missing UUID ********************************)
> 7  FirebaseFirestore              0xd0f50 (Missing UUID ********************************)
> 8  FirebaseFirestore              0xc701c (Missing UUID 8********************************)
> 9  FirebaseFirestore              0xdf108 (Missing UUID ********************************)
> 10 FirebaseFirestore              0x6b344 (Missing UUID ********************************)
> 11 FirebaseFirestore              0x6190 (Missing UUID ********************************)
> 12 FirebaseFirestore              0x147528 (Missing UUID ********************************)
> 13 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout
> 14 libdispatch.dylib              0x746c _dispatch_continuation_pop
> 15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1aa58 _dispatch_source_invoke
> 16 libdispatch.dylib              0xb56c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain
> 17 libdispatch.dylib              0xc1e0 _dispatch_lane_invoke
> 18 libdispatch.dylib              0x16e10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
> 19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xdf8 _pthread_wqthread
> 20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xb98 start_wqthread
> ````

From xcode

> FirebaseFirestore: std::__1::enable_if<!(std::is_same<void, decltype(fp0())>::value), decltype(fp0())>::type firebase::firestore::local::Persistence::Run<firebase::firestore::local::LocalStore::CollectGarbage(firebas... + 64

I have tried persisting version

```
firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1

I have tried turning on and off data to recreate it seems not to occur only spiratically when phone goes into standby.
```

My main is ....

```dart
Future main() async {
  RenderErrorBox.backgroundColor = Colors.transparent;

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  Stripe.publishableKey = stripePublishableKey;
  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  ); //initialise shared preferences   PreferenceUtils.init();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Formatted Crashlytics

[Crashlyticsformat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afEVW.png)

XCODE CRASH LOG

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10FXS.png)

Comment: The issue seems related to Firestore but in the code I didn't see any Firestore reference. Would it be possible to share a screenshot of the formatted crash in Crashlytics? (not the TXT format) I'm interested to see what frame is being blamed. Lastly, the "Missing UUID" from those Firestore frames indicate that the related symbols (dSYMs) were not uploaded to Crashlytics. Try uploading those symbols, that could give some extra hints into the issue.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. Will upload those symbols now and see what results come out of it. I have also updated the post with a screen shot of the crashlytics formatting.

Answer (score -1):

make sure that binding has been initialized!

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I have checked my main this is in the current version Future main() async {
  RenderErrorBox.backgroundColor = Colors.transparent;

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );